# Is it possible to run AVD in Kali Linux which is running in VirtualBox?

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-virtual-device, haxm

So my question is already in title.

I'm asking it because I left it for an hour and a half and still nothing, still booting up. I tried everything, adding more ram (2gb), from 1 core adding an other core of CPU. I know I have a support for HAXM, because installing HAXM in Windows and checking if it is running in CMD `sc query intelhaxm` it says 4 RUNNING, but when I try to install KVM in Kali I get a 0 for `egrep -c'(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`, which means that my cpu does not have support, and it actually has it.

I can not switch to Genymotion because I need to used it in DroidBox for my dynamic Android analysis.

Windows 10 is my host OS where is VirtualBox 5.0.0. installed. Version of Kali is 1.0.9 64 bit. CPU i5-3230M

Comment: You are trying to run an operating system (Android) inside of another operating system (Linux) inside of another operating system (Windows). I would expect that to perform poorly.

Comment: i know that, but taking it so long to start it, is THAT normal? so what would you recommend? Installing Kali AS-IS on hard drive not virtually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in API version. I was using API 19 (4.4.2) and i needed to use API 16 (4.1.2) and emulator is now working. Not as fast but is working with DroidBox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run avd in kali linux virtual box. both of them uses the same kernel. but thats not the issue linux supports avd.check the log for more information. the configuration u r trying is correct